# Evaluating a Lie Derivative of a Meromorphic Complex Form over a Holomorphic Vector Field.

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Given a meromorphic form $\omega : \Omega^{1, 0}$, we can get the form $\; \mathrm{d}\omega = \partial \omega + \bar \partial \omega \;$ through the use of Dolbeault operators.

I'm trying to find the lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_v \; \omega$, where $v$ is a holomorphic vector field. How can I find this for non-holomorphic forms?

For example, suppose we allow the following definitions: $$ \omega = \frac{z+4}{z-3i} \; \mathrm{d}z, \quad v = 2z-1.$$

What is the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_v \;\omega$?

Comment: Is your $\langle \mathbb X, d \omega \rangle$ off by a sign? Since $ \langle \partial_x, d x \wedge d y \rangle = d y$ ? Not that it should matter much...

Comment: @CarlosEsparza You may be right, I'll check my work. Other than that, does this seem right?

Comment: @CarlosEsparza I fixed the issue, thank you.

Comment: Isn't a meromorphic form just a (locally) holomorphic form (perhaps with values in the sphere)?

Comment: @Keshav Yes, but poles exist at discrete points in the form. Would this not effect the answer?

Comment: I meant it is still "holomorphic" at those poles, no? Use a (holomorphic) chart around $\infty$ on the sphere, and now it's represented by a holomorphic form.

Comment: @Keshav I am speaking of this on the complexes and not on the extended complexes, apologies. $\infty$ is not a well-behaved construct in this case.

Comment: Hmm, this should be the intuition then. Meromorphic functions/forms behave the same as holomorphic functions/forms, even at their poles: if $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function with a pole at $z=0$, then $1/f$ can be extended to be a holomorphic function over $z=0$. So it's (lie) derivative should behave the same as well.

Comment: @Keshav I suppose I wonder how a meromorphic function behaves the same at the poles? A jump from $\infty$ to $-\infty$ does not seem to act similarly. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117672/discussion-between-keshav-and-jayzenvia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically enough, I feel able enough to finally respond  with an answer.

Given complex 1-form $$\omega = \alpha(z) \mathrm \; {d}z, \qquad \alpha \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{C}), \qquad \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \bar z} = 0 \; $$ and given vector field $v = \beta(z) \; \partial_z, $ where $\beta$ is holomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, define the Lie derivative like such:

$$\mathcal{L}_v \; \omega = i_v \circ d\omega + d \circ i_v\omega.$$

$$\mathcal{L}_v \; \omega = \; \Big(\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \bar{z}}\Big)\beta \;\mathrm{d}\bar z + \frac{\partial(\alpha \beta)}{\partial z} \, \mathrm{d}z + \frac{\partial(\alpha \beta)}{\partial \bar z} \, \mathrm{d}\bar z.$$

Using the fact that $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \bar z} = \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \bar z} = 0$, the final result can be determined:

$$\mathcal{L}_v \; \omega = (\alpha \beta)'_z \; \mathrm{d}z + \alpha'_z \beta \; \mathrm{d}\bar{z}.$$

This is a surprisingly beautiful and simple result.